# AWS S3 - Multipart upload with input stream

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload my input stream as a multipart upload in S3(to achieve re-try mechanism). If any error occurred during upload or conversion, I need to resume from that point. When I trying to upload it will return an exception like `Your socket connection to the server was not read from or written to within the timeout period. Idle connections will be closed.`

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
   PartETag partETag = uploadObjectAsMultipart(s3Client, bucketName, initResponse.getUploadId(), stringBuilder, 1, fileName, file);
   combineMultiPartUpload(s3Client, bucketName, fileName, initResponse.getUploadId(), new ArrayList<PartETag>(){{add(partETag);}});
}
public static PartETag uploadObjectAsMultipart(AmazonS3Client s3Client, String bucketName, String uploadId, StringBuilder stringBuilder, int partNumber, String fileName, File file) {
        UploadPartRequest uploadRequest =
                new UploadPartRequest()
                        .withBucketName(bucketName)
                        .withUploadId(uploadId)
                        .withKey(fileName)
                        .withPartNumber(partNumber)
                        .withInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(stringBuilder.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)))
                        .withPartSize(5 * 1024 * 1024);

        return s3Client.uploadPart(uploadRequest).getPartETag();
    }

    public static void combineMultiPartUpload(AmazonS3Client s3Client, String bucketName, String fileName, String uploadId, List<PartETag> partETags) {
        CompleteMultipartUploadRequest compRequest =
                new CompleteMultipartUploadRequest(bucketName,
                        fileName,
                        uploadId,
                        partETags);

        s3Client.completeMultipartUpload(compRequest);
    }
```